# Using android's native audio vs using audiocontext

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm creating this app that's based on playing sounds. I've tried to run it with audiocontext and I found out that it was running beautifully. Background sounds was perfect, even when I close the screen.

If audiocontext is working so great what's the point of using native audio? There must be something that I'm missing here.

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio

https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/blob/master/howler.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is save to use native audio, because audiocontext might not work in all phones.